# CSS Hyperlink Animation fails when words wrap at the margin

Tags: css, animation

Here's an example of a CSS hyperlink animation from [this article](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/):

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #F00;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F00;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p>As armas e os barões assinalados, que da <a href="#">ocidental praia</a> lusitana, por mares <a href="#">nunca dantes navegados, passaram ainda além da trapobana</a>.</p>
```

The effect is of the underline progressively appearing (through scaling) form the center to the outline. This is a nice effect accomplished by the `:before` trick.

However, it completely breaks up when hyperlinks wrap at the margin, and I can't think of any way to fix it...

Comment: wrap at margin means?

Comment: Just added a runnnable snippet to better illustrate my problem. The first hyperlink animates as axpected; but the second one, because the words wrap into a new line, doesn't.

Comment: This is a great question, but why would you want a link that long?

Comment: @balapa true... its a great question. but you cant ask like why such a long link. coz it happens more often

Comment: @jafarbtech yeah, i think you're right
@HugoSFerreira you can use `display: inline-block` to your link, but the animation only works at the bottom part of the link. Probably because the browser couldn't determine the center coordinate of the link.

Comment: @balapa, the long link was just for easing the construction of the example. This happens all the time with shorter links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the psuedo elements wont take multiple lines. you can use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent it from wrapping to the next line and animation will look consistent. Even though nothing works as good as like an `underline`

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a:hover {
  color: #F00;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F00;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p>As armas e os barões assinalados, que da <a href="#">ocidental praia</a> lusitana, por mares <a href="#">nunca dantes navegados, passaram ainda além da trapobana</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the pseudo-element won't be applied over multiple lines. One workround could be to prevent those line-breaks of the link content.

To achieve this simply add `display: inline-block` to the `a` tag

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover {
  color: #F00;
}
a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #F00;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<p>As armas e os barões assinalados, que da <a href="#">ocidental praia</a> lusitana, por mares <a href="#">nunca dantes navegados, passaram ainda além da trapobana</a> As armas e os barões assinalados, que da.</p>
```

Comment: I think I might have not made myself clear on what *margin* I was talking about :) Please check my runnable script above. The problem is when words "wrap" at the end of a line...

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` has the side-effect of slightly shifting to the right the first word of a paragraph if it is a link... do you know why that happens?